# Home button visible angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello is there any way to make the home button of a page visible only when someone is logged in ?I think it is something possible in angular 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it in Angular 2. You can use `*ngif` directive to check weather user is login or not.

For Example:

```
<a href="#" *ngif="isLogin"> Home</a>
```

if the value of `isLogin` is true then only the `Home` link is visible.